# How to use multiple keras models in a single thread?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use pretrained and saved keras models for prediction. I trained and saved the models to json files in different threads with:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
json_file.write(model_json)
```

When I tried to use these models, I need to read them one by one and get prediction results. The first one works well. However when it comes to the second model, I read it from json file and run `model.predict(dataToPredict)`,
it returns an error indicating that the layers are not the element of the graph. Here is the error:

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("conv_layer1_input:0", shape=(?, 1182, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

I used

```
json_file = open(path, 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
with tf.Session():
    model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    predictionResult = model.predict(dataToPredict)
```

for each model and it didn't raise the error this time. However, it seems **weights of the models are randomly generated, not read from the file** or I initialized them by mistake with this `with tf.Session():`. That's why they produce different results every time I run them with the same data. I also tried using:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
```

without `with tf.Session():` but it raised the same error again.
I am confused about "graph" and "session" terms. I thought keras manages both graph and session. If so, what is the problem? Here is my prediction code:

```
predictions = []
for modelFilePath in modelFilePaths:
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    json_file = open(modelFilePath , 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    predictions.append(model.predict(dataToPredict))
```

Comment: It turned out that, using `with tf.Session():` for each model works well. The problem about weights was because I didin't load weights using `model.load_weights(weightsFilePath)` after loading the models.  I thought that saving the model also saves the weights but they are supposed to be saved seperately.